# PostgresOperator AirflowProviderDeprecationWarning: This class is deprecated

Tags: postgresql, airflow

[pic PostgresOperator is deprecated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMNFr.jpg)

this is my code

```
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator

create_pet_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="create_pet_table",
        sql="""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet (
            pet_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            pet_type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
            OWNER VARCHAR NOT NULL);
          """,
        dag=dag,
        postgres_conn_id = "postgres_local",
    )
```

i run my file and it got error like this

```
/home/manew001/airflow/dags/pet.py:30 AirflowProviderDeprecationWarning: This class is deprecated.
            Please use `airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql.SQLExecuteQueryOperator`.
            Also, you can provide `hook_params={'schema': <database>}`.
```

i am so confuse is PostgresOperator really deprecated? and if i use SQLExecuteQueryOperator instead how can i connect to my postgres?

Comment: What did it do when you tried it?

Comment: When i run dag the table is not created

Answer (score 2):

The `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` is a newly developed generic operator used for executing queries on various databases. Its key feature lies in the Airflow connection and hook, where you pass the id of your connection as an argument through the `conn_id` parameter. When the provided id if for a connection of type `postgres`, the operator creates a PostgreSQL hook that allows the operator to execute the query in your PostgreSQL database.